# React Native: 'Component' cannot be used as a JSX component. Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, npm, intellisense

I just started a new project but i'm getting the following error with various packages, for example React Native Reanimated and React Navigation Stack.

This is my package.json.

```
{
  "name": "foodmatch",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "prepare": "yarn husky install",
    "lint": "yarn eslint --ext .tsx --ext .ts src/ --fix",
    "format": "yarn prettier --write ./src"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{ts,tsx}": [
      "eslint --ext .tsx --ext .ts src/ --fix"
    ],
    "./src/**": [
      "prettier --write ./src"
    ]
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "expo": "~44.0.2",
    "expo-app-loading": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-font": "^10.0.5",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.14.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.64.12",
    "@types/styled-components-react-native": "^5.1.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.20.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.20.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.13.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.4.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "lint-staged": "^12.3.8",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

This is the error.

```
'Navigator' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its element type 'ReactElement<any, any> | Component<Omit<DefaultRouterOptions<string> & { id?: string | undefined; children: ReactNode; screenListeners?: Partial<...> | ... 1 more ... | undefined; screenOptions?: StackNavigationOptions | ... 1 more ... | undefined; defaultScreenOptions?: StackNavigationOptions | ... 1 more ... | und...' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Component<Omit<DefaultRouterOptions<string> & { id?: string | undefined; children: ReactNode; screenListeners?: Partial<{ transitionStart: EventListenerCallback<StackNavigationEventMap, "transitionStart">; ... 7 more ...; beforeRemove: EventListenerCallback<...>; }> | ((props: { ...; }) => Partial<...>) | undefined;...' is not assignable to type 'Element | ElementClass | null'.
      Type 'Component<Omit<DefaultRouterOptions<string> & { id?: string | undefined; children: ReactNode; screenListeners?: Partial<{ transitionStart: EventListenerCallback<StackNavigationEventMap, "transitionStart">; ... 7 more ...; beforeRemove: EventListenerCallback<...>; }> | ((props: { ...; }) => Partial<...>) | undefined;...' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass'.
        The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/Users/bilug/Documents/Repositorios/foodMatch/node_modules/@types/react-native/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
            Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
```

```
'Animated.View' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'View' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/Users/bilug/Documents/Repositorios/foodMatch/node_modules/@types/react-native/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2786)
```

I have a project with the same packages and configuration (babel, eslint, etc) and it works fine, it looks like a type error because the project works just like it is intended to, but IntelliSense claims these errors.

I also get the following when i try to use one of the components with Styled() from styled-components.

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(component: AnyStyledComponent): ThemedStyledFunction<any, DefaultTheme, any, any>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'typeof Text' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyStyledComponent'.
      Type 'typeof Text' is not assignable to type 'StyledComponent<any, any, any, never>'.
        Type 'typeof Text' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(component: ComponentType<any>): ThemedStyledFunction<ComponentType<any>, DefaultTheme, {}, never>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'typeof Text' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<any>'.
      Type 'typeof Text' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<any, any>'.
        Types of property 'contextType' are incompatible.
          Type 'React.Context<any> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/Users/bilug/Documents/Repositorios/foodMatch/node_modules/@types/react-native/node_modules/@types/react/index").Context<any> | undefined'.
            Type 'React.Context<any>' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/Users/bilug/Documents/Repositorios/foodMatch/node_modules/@types/react-native/node_modules/@types/react/index").Context<any>'.
              The types of 'Provider.propTypes' are incompatible between these types.
                Type 'React.WeakValidationMap<React.ProviderProps<any>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/Users/bilug/Documents/Repositorios/foodMatch/node_modules/@types/react-native/node_modules/@types/react/index").WeakValidationMap<import("D:/Users/bilug/Documents/Repositorios/foodMatch/node_modules/@types/react-native/node_modules/@types/react/index").ProviderProps<any>> | undefined'.
                  Type 'React.WeakValidationMap<React.ProviderProps<any>>' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/Users/bilug/Documents/Repositorios/foodMatch/node_modules/@types/react-native/node_modules/@types/react/index").WeakValidationMap<import("D:/Users/bilug/Documents/Repositorios/foodMatch/node_modules/@types/react-native/node_modules/@types/react/index").ProviderProps<any>>'.
                    Types of property 'children' are incompatible.
                      Type 'React.Validator<React.ReactNode> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/Users/bilug/Documents/Repositorios/foodMatch/node_modules/@types/react-native/node_modules/@types/react/index").Validator<import("D:/Users/bilug/Documents/Repositorios/foodMatch/node_modules/@types/react-native/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode> | undefined'.
                        Type 'React.Validator<React.ReactNode>' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/Users/bilug/Documents/Repositorios/foodMatch/node_modules/@types/prop-types/index").Validator<import("D:/Users/bilug/Documents/Repositorios/foodMatch/node_modules/@types/react-native/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode>'.
                          Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/Users/bilug/Documents/Repositorios/foodMatch/node_modules/@types/react-native/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
                            Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2769)
```

Comment: This question is already discussed and answered at https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/10507 and https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/59765#issuecomment-1092891129 Adding `@types/react` to resolutions at package.json should fix it. `"resolutions": { "@types/react": "17.0.43" }`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Adding `@types/react` to `resolutions` in package.json fixed it:

```json
"resolutions": { "@types/react": "17.0.43" }
```

- https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/10507
- https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/59765#issuecomment-1092891129

Comment: react and @types/react version should be match

Answer (score 6):

I added the following dependencies and it solved the problem:

```
"@types/react-dom": "17.0.14",
"@types/react": "~18.0.0",
"@types/react-native": "~0.69.1",
```

https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/15802#issuecomment-1205018068

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @RezaBabaei.

The fix for me was, not in `resolutions`. My issue was:

My `"@types/react"` was at `"~17.0.21",`

And my `"react":` was at `"17.0.1",`

***They need to match.***

As soon as I set my `"@types/react"` to match react at `"~17.0.1",` and ran `install`. It immediately fixed my issue. I also could have just updated both. None of the other solutions worked for me

Answer (score 3):

**"resolutions": {
"@types/react": "17.0.43"
},**

add this to package.json

**delete** (node modules) and **yarn or npm  install** again

Answer (score 3):

just use same version for @types/react and react like

```
"@types/react": "18.2.0",


"react": "18.2.0",
```

If it work it is superb else also add

```
"resolutions": { "@types/react": "18.2.0" } in package.json
```

Answer (score 3):

The below steps helped me to resolve this issue:

1. Add below in `compilerOptions` of `tsconfig.json/jsconfig.json` file.

```
"jsx": "react-native",
"paths": { "react": ["./node_modules/@types/react"] },
```

2. Add below in `package.json` file (replace value with your react version).

```json
"resolutions": { "@types/react": "~17.0.38" }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was fixed when I deleted

```
node_modules and package-lock.json
```

and then

```
run "npm i"
```