# React Native Elements Cannot Be Used As A JSX Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

Hello everyone I am getting this error in my RN project :
"'View' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its instance type 'View' is not a valid JSX element"
This was a project that I cloned I didn't created it. All the React Native elements are outputting the same error, It's not just View. I tried everything but couldn't come up with a solution.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "retail-mobile",
  "version": "2.154.0",
  "private": true,
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios --simulator=\"iPhone 11 (15.5)\"",
    "start": "react-native start -- --reset-cache > /dev/null",
    "version:major": "npm version major -no-git-tag-version",
    "version:minor": "npm version minor -no-git-tag-version",
    "version:patch": "npm version patch -no-git-tag-version",
    "codepush": " yarn push:staging && yarn push:production",
    "push:staging": "yarn version:patch && npx json -I -f app.json -e \"this.enrollVersion='Staging'\" && yarn push:staging:ios &&  yarn push:staging:android ",
    "push:production": "yarn version:minor && npx json -I -f app.json -e \"this.enrollVersion='Production'\" && yarn push:ios  && yarn push:android ",
    "push:ios": "appcenter codepush release-react -a maple-tech/retail-mobile -d Production --mandatory -t '5.6.0'",
    "push:android": "appcenter codepush release-react -a maple-tech/retail-mobile-1 -d Production --mandatory -t '2.4.0'",
    "push:staging:ios": "appcenter codepush release-react -a maple-tech/retail-mobile -d Staging --mandatory -t '5.0.1'",
    "push:staging:android": "yarn version:patch && npx json -I -f app.json -e \"this.enrollVersion='Staging'\" && appcenter codepush release-react -a maple-tech/retail-mobile-1 -d Staging --mandatory -t '2.0.2'",
    "push:android-alpha": "yarn version:patch && npx json -I -f app.json -e \"this.enrollVersion='Staging'\" && yarn push:staging:android",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
    "auto:push": "git add . ; git commit -m 'Auto Commit'; git push -u ",
    "npm-pod-install": "yarn && npx pod-install",
    "clear-npm-pod-cache": "rm -rf ios/Podfile.lock && rm -rf package-lock.json && npx pod-install",
    "clear-cache": "bash ./resetXcode.sh && watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && npm cache verify && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm run clear-npm-pod-cache && rm -rf ios/build/ ",
    "build:android-debug": "detox build -c android.emu.debug",
    "build:android-release": "detox build -c android.emu.release",
    "build:ios-debug": "detox build -c ios.sim.debug",
    "build:ios-release": "detox build -c ios.sim.release",
    "test:android-debug": "detox test -c android.emu.debug -l verbose",
    "test:android-release": "detox test -c android.emu.release -l verbose",
    "test:ios-debug": "detox test -c ios.sim.debug -l verbose",
    "test:ios-release": "detox test -c ios.sim.release -l verbose",
    "test:ios-none": "detox test -c ios.none -l verbose",
    "detox-server": "detox run-server"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@archireport/react-native-svg-draw": "^1.0.2",
    "@dudigital/react-native-zoomable-view": "^1.1.3",
    "@emotion/native": "^11.0.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.3.1",
    "@motify/interactions": "^0.17.1",
    "@native-html/table-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.5",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/hooks": "^2.8.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^7.1.12",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^14.11.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.11.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^14.11.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^14.11.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/in-app-messaging": "^14.11.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.11.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/perf": "^14.11.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/core": "^6.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "@terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas": "^0.8.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "color": "3.2.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.2",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "hi-base32": "^0.5.1",
    "i18next": "^21.8.5",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.4.1",
    "intl-pluralrules": "^1.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lottie-ios": "3.2.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "^5.1.3",
    "moti": "^0.18.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-i18next": "^11.16.7",
    "react-native": "^0.67.3",
    "react-native-action-sheet": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1284.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-code-push": "^7.0.4",
    "react-native-config": "^1.4.5",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.7.1",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-emoji-selector": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.5.11",
    "react-native-file-viewer": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-flipper": "^0.146.1",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.37.3",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.4.5",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-lightbox": "^0.8.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-localize": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-maps": "0.31.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.24",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.1",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.5",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-share": "^7.4.1",
    "react-native-signature-canvas": "^4.3.0",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.6.1",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.21.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.8",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "rn-placeholder": "^3.0.3",
    "url-parse": "^1.5.10",
    "victory-native": "^36.4.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "yup": "^0.32.11",
    "zustand": "4.0.0-rc.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.17.12",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.18.3",
    "@types/color": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.182",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.9",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.67.7",
    "@types/react-native-calendars": "^1.1264.3",
    "@types/react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.8.1",
    "@types/react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.0",
    "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.5",
    "@types/react-native-svg-charts": "^5.0.12",
    "@types/react-native-table-component": "^1.2.4",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.10",
    "@types/react-native-video": "^5.0.13",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/redux": "^3.6.0",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.9",
    "@types/redux-saga": "^0.10.5",
    "@types/xlsx": "^0.0.36",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.14",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.26.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.26.0",
    "babel-jest": "^28.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "detox": "^19.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "fs-extra": "^10.1.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.0",
    "jest-circus": "^28.1.0",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "json": "^11.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.70.2",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "react-devtools": "^4.24.6",
    "react-native-clean-project": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-flipper-zustand": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.7.0",
    "redux-flipper": "^2.0.1",
    "rn-async-storage-flipper": "^0.0.10",
    "sanitize-filename": "^1.6.3",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.2"
  }
}
```

I added

```
"resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Make sure you have a react-native environment installed correctly on PC. And install node modules. before that delete the node_modules folder and package-lock.json file if it's in the project.

Comment: This is the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71916289/react-native-component-cannot-be-used-as-a-jsx-component-type-is-not-as See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71916657/841344