# React Native with Expo jsx component warning

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo, jsx

Hello everybody my problems

I did worked a project with expo on react native. I want component in react-native but it's give me  warning.

problem: "[React Native: 'Component' cannot be used as a JSX component.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71916289/react-native-component-cannot-be-used-as-a-jsx-component-type-is-not-as)"

What can I do this for situation

```
import { SafeAreaView, View } from "react-native";
```

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "suratesnafnoktasi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21"
  },

  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.43"
  },
  
  "private": true
}
```

I want in node_modules component but give me warning

Comment: There is not enough information to reproduce the issue. Please provide minimal working example that show the issue you have.